# How to set complex join conditions in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to encode a query to a database using sequelize. This is exactly the sentence I want to transcript:

```
SELECT matches.uid_prop, matches.uid_player, matches.porcentaje, users.uid, profile_users.name, profile_users.profile, profile_users.birthday, profile_users.location
FROM (matches JOIN users ON (((matches.uid_prop = users.uid) AND (matches.uid_player = 11)) OR ((matches.uid_player = users.uid) AND (matches.uid_prop = 11)))) JOIN profile_users USING(uid)
WHERE (matches.uid_player = 11) OR (matches.uid_prop = 11);
```

I don't know if I should change the associations in order to build the join condition as I want

```
Matches.belongsTo(User, {as: 'match_prop', foreignKey: 'uid_prop'});
User.hasMany(Matches, {as: 'user_prop', foreignKey: 'uid_prop'});

Matches.belongsTo(User, {as: 'match_player', foreignKey: 'uid_player'});
User.hasMany(Matches, {as: 'user_player', foreignKey: 'uid_player'});
```

or add a where and specify the relation at the include between matches and user. If that's the case, how could I make reference to a field of matches from a where statement in the include made with user so I could compare, e.g., User.uid and Matches.uid_prop.
I've tried this notation but it didn't work: $Matches.uid_prop$

```
Matches.findAll({
                attributes: ['porcentaje'],
                where: {
                    $or: [
                        {uid_prop: uid},
                        {uid_player: uid}
                    ]
                },
                include: [{
                    model: User,
                    attributes: ['uid'],
                    include: [{
                        model: Profile_user,
                        attributes: ['name', 'profile', 'birthday', 'location']
                    }]
                }]
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need is `required : true` ( INNER JOIN ) like :

```
Matches.findAll({
                    attributes: ['porcentaje'],
                    where: {
                        $or: [
                            {uid_prop: uid},
                            {uid_player: uid}
                        ]
                    },
                    include: [{
                        model: User,
                        attributes: ['uid'],
                        required : true , //<-------- HERE -------
                        include: [{
                            model: Profile_user,
                            attributes: ['name', 'profile', 'birthday', 'location']
                        }]
                    }]
                })
```

Your query is making the LEFT JOIN , to make it INNER JOIN force fully , you can use `required : true`.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. Here's the resultant join condition:

`FROM "matches" AS "matches" INNER JOIN "users" AS "user" ON "matches"."uid_player" = "user"."uid" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profile_users" AS "user.profile_user" ON "user"."uid" = "user.profile_user"."uid"`

Wich's not:

`FROM (matches JOIN users ON (((matches.uid_prop = users.uid) AND (matches.uid_player = 11)) OR ((matches.uid_player = users.uid) AND (matches.uid_prop = 11)))) JOIN profile_users USING(uid)`

It's just using 1 association, there's someway to make sequelize use both to construct the query?